# How am I leaking NSString in this case?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, instruments, memory-leaks

I have a tableview that has a string on the last row.

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSString *loadingMessage;   
}
@property (retain) NSString *loadingMessage;
@synthesize loadingMessage;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//some stuff...
        cell.textLabel.text = loadingMessage;
}
```

Then when some event happens, I will be changing the loading message:

```
-(void)requestFailed:(NSError*)error {
    self.loadingMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed with error: %@", error];
}
```

According to instruments I am leaking the loadingMessage string in here... But I don't see why. I thought the count for stringWithFormat is +0, and the setter is +1. I release the string when I dealloc as well. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: From what I can see, there's nothing wrong. Are you doing this test in an isolated test, or in a program where other NSStrings might be at fault?

Comment: Not on an isolated test, but this is the only ivar that instrument report leaks from...

Comment: Show code that uses and sets the loadingMessage. Also, did you release it in dealloc?

Comment: I've shown you right? I used it in cellForRowAtIndexPath and set that in requestFailed. I did mentioned I released it in dealloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is correct. Indeed, `stringWithFormat` returns an autoreleased object, so you can assign it directly to a retained property.

So, either you are doing some other assignment in your code, or, more probably, you are not releasing `loadingMessage` in your `dealloc`.

Just an hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio is right , theres nothing wrong with the code but I have found that string properties need to be copy rather than retain.

Try

`@property (copy,readwrite) NSString *loadingMessage;`

Might stop the leak